# Angular 2 submitting dynamic form

Tags: angular

My DB has `Questions`, every question has 1-N `questionTypes` and a question with a `questionType` has 0-N possible `answers`

[image]

Im trying to implement a form with Angular 2 like this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9YSs9txF6wR8ogX7PTdY?p=preview) where I can insert as many answers(label+value) as I want with the `add button` and then save the answers for individual type with the `save button`.

The problem is that I dont know how to finish It, ¿any help?

Comment: finish it means ?

Comment: if u go to the plnkr is not working as expected when you insert a new answer because is inseerted to both questions

Answer (score 1):

You must use `FormBuilder` if you want to use arrays in a form:

```
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder} {}

public questionsForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  questions: this.fb.array([])
});

addInfo(label: string, value: string): void {

  const questions: FormArray = <FormArray>this.questionsForm.get('questions');

  questions.push(this.fb.group({label: label, value: value}));

  this.label = '';
  this.value = '';
}

saveQuestion(): void {

  // This will give you {questions: [{label: '', value: ''}, ...]}
  const formValue = this.questionsForm.value;
}
```

And then template:

```
<form [formGroup]="questionsForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuestion()" novalidate>
  <div *ngFor="let info of questionForm.get('questions').controls" [formGroup]="info">
    <input formControlName="label>
    <input formControlName="value">
  </div>

  <input [(ngModel]="label" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" placeholder="label">
  <input [(ngModel]="value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" placeholder="value">

  <button (click)="addInfo(label, value)">Add</button>

  <p>
    <button type="submit">Save Question</button>
  </p>
</form>
```